# Installing GCC from source on Alpine

Tags: linux, gcc, gmp, alpine-linux, lib

While trying to install GCC 6.4.0 on Alpine, I run into:

```
checking for the correct version of gmp.h... yes
checking for the correct version of mpfr.h... yes
checking for the correct version of mpc.h... yes
checking for the correct version of the gmp/mpfr/mpc libraries... no
```

But in `/usr/lib`, which seems to be the standard lookup directory, I have:

```
libgmp.a
libgmp.so
libgmp.so.10
libgmp.so.10.3.2
libmpc.so.3
libmpc.so.3.0.0
libmpfr.so.4
libmpfr.so.4.1.5
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: `config.log` may have details on why the check failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that in this particular case one needs to install mpc1-dev, gmp-dev or mpfr-dev. I was missing out on mpc1-dev.

```
sudo apk add mpc1-dev
```

Answer (score 64):

The quickest way to install GCC on Alpine Linux is by issuing the following command:

```
apk add build-base
```

source: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/GCC

Comment: Fixed issues I was having on Alpine with Emacs Org-Roam. I was getting the following error message "no emacsql sqlite binary available aborting". Attempts to just install gcc and cmake directly didn't work but the above works. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

The best way to install all necessary libraries to compile `gcc` is using `./contrib/download_prerequisites` script in the `gcc` source directory. That will download the support libraries and create symlinks, causing them to be built automatically as part of the `gcc` build process.

The steps to compile `gcc` version `6.4.0` on Alpine linux are:

```
apk add --no-cache make build-base
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-6.4.0/gcc-6.4.0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf gcc-6.4.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-6.4.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
./../gcc-6.4.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/GCC-6.4.0 --disable-multilib
make all-gcc
make all-target-libgcc
make install-gcc
make install-target-libgcc
```